# Laravel 5 unable to render pagination

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I'm new to Laravel 5 and I have an issue displaying pagination. I looked in the documentation and just can't get it to work.

usercontroller:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $users = User::where('active', '=','verified')->simplePaginate(10);
    return View::make('User.index')->with('users',$users);
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>username</th>
                    <th>email</th>
                    <th>role</th>
                    <th>created</th>
                    <th class="actions">Actions</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->role }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
                        <td class="actions">
                            blabla
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
{!! $users->render() !!}
```

Comment: What happens? It looks good to me. Are you sure you have more than 10 items? If there's only 1 page, then no pagination is displayed

Comment: i don't have 10 items indeed, but shouldn't it display page 1 of 1 or something

Comment: You'd have to override the default page functionality if you wanted it to. By default it doesn't show any pagination if there's only 1 page

Comment: What is the URL? Pagination should just append a get variable, e.g. if this URL is `/users` then page 2 should be `/users?page=2`.

Comment: the generated link of next button is http://localhost/laravel5/public/users/index **/** ?page=2 so it fails

Comment: what's the URL of page 1? i don't see any problem with that URL. How exactly is it failing, what error does it give?

Comment: I fixed it by doing `{!! str_replace('users/','users',$users->render()) !!}` it's bad but I don't know any better solution.

Comment: Use `paginate()` rather than `simplePaginate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, it was printing an additional `/`

fix:

```
{!! str_replace('users/','users',$users->render()) !!}
```